# Help for deploying Magento2 on AWS

Tags: magento2, aws

Help for deploying Magento2 on AWS

-

Implanted the following project

http://648050603631-test-webapp011.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

By accessing

http://648050603631-test-webapp011.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/magento/

The home page should be displayed but the installation page is loaded even though the files

```
app/etc/config.php
app/etc/env.php
```

According to the documentation at https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/config/config-php.html

-

Another thing I noticed is that when executing the command `./bin/magento` as images in the local environment the "cache" option is displayed but in AWS or any server this command possibility is not displayed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4NoQ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9T1m.jpg

-

If necessary, you can confirm the presence of the files by accessing the

http://648050603631-test-webapp011.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/backdoor/commando/

and running

```
cat /var/app/current/magento/app/etc/config.php
cat /var/app/current/magento/app/etc/env.php
```

-

Comment: I think files & folder are not copied properly and permission issue has

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of creating env.php, I came up with the option "bin / magento setup: config: set" but in this way the "install-> date" attribute is not created.

I am using the following example

https://github.com/marcinbojanowski/docker-magento-web/blob/1949c75d7b238e71ef32e2b22202a2f491635f90/rootfs/etc/cont-init.d/20-magento